# Event passing to sibling on clicking a view

Tags: android

I have a simple `LinearLayout(horizontal)` with 3 `TextView`s. The background of these `TextView`s are set to a drawable that has two states, `state_pressed` and default. I simply change the background of each `TextView` to red on state_pressed.
But when i click one `TextView`, its click listener is invoked but background of all 3 changes to red. This is happening on Android 2.x and working fine on Android 4.0+.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/swipe_list_leftoffest"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:background="@color/list_swipe_back"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:tag="back">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/amenities_view"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
                    android:background="@drawable/swipe_view_background"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_large"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/amenities_text"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_amenities"
                    />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/cancpolicy_view"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:background="@drawable/swipe_view_background"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/canc_policy_text"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_cancellation_policy"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:id="@+id/reviews_view"
                android:background="@drawable/swipe_view_background"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/reviews_text"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_reviews"
                />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Tried putting focusable and focusableInTouchMode false for each of the TextViews, but that didnt help.

Comment: paste your @drawable/ic_cancellation_policy.xml

Comment: That is an image.Its not xml.

Comment: ok then you have to separate with id as @Kelevandos suggest

Comment: add your snippet about if else condition that you mentioned in comment

Comment: I have simply written if(v.getId()==someting), then do this else if v.getId()==smthingelse, then do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 3 separate onClickListeners for the TextViews? If you have only one, this may be the problem and you could solve it by doing something like this in the listener:

```
public void onClick(View v){
   switch(v.getId()){
      case R.id.amenities_view:
          //Click first
          break;
      case R.id.cancpolicy_view:
          //Click second
          break;
      case R.id.reviews_view:
          //Click third
          break;
   }
}
```

If you do not create this switch, all the views associated with the listener will react to the click.

Comment: I have written the same thing in an If else if condition

Comment: Then try to provide three separate onClickListeners for the TextViews. I think that the selector is invoked _before_ the onClick method of the listener. You could also create an onTouchListener and differentiate this manually, but creating 3 onClickListeners will be quicker and cleaner.